# Launch only one chromium instance

Tags: chromium, openbox, xdotool, lxpanel

I'm running Chromium from snap storage at Ubuntu 20.04 with Openbox and minimal install. How can I run only one instance of Chromium browser by each additional click in panel (lxpanel) or launch `chromium`-command from Xterm-terminal? My intention is that an (older) user, for him I make this installation, did not produce new instances of Chromium, if he accidentally click on Chromium icon in panel. `chromium --help` does not show me the option for that I search. Currently, when I try in similar situation, any launch of `chromium` command launches a new chromium window of the same profile. Ideally I would like to get some advice how to focus already running Chromium window.

Comment: Hello. A Google search of your exact title brings up this question. The accepted answer may solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028526/how-to-prevent-more-than-once-instance-of-chrome-app-being-open-at-a-time

Comment: @David: unfortunately this answer does not help me. I don't know enough to interpret them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flag may exist for Chromium that would allow having it focus an existing window when it is launched again, but I could not find one. By default, it will create a new blank line.

A simple approach to obtain the behavior you want is to use a (very) small script, actually a one-liner. that uses the tool `wmctrl` to check if a window of Chromium exists. If it exists, the window will be put in focus, if it doesn't, the executable will be run. The nice thing is that the approach can work for any application.

- Launch chromium and then determine the window class of the chromium window with the command `wmctrl -lx` in the terminal.

  ```
  0x04200003  0 chromium-browser.Chromium-browser  vanadium New Tab - Chromium
  ```
- You can launch or switch to Chromium with the following command:

  ```
  sh -c "wmctrl -x -a Chromium.browser || chromium-browser"
  ```
- Create a copy of the `.desktop` launcher for Chromium in the `~/.local/share/applications` directory of the user. Edit the copy, and substitute the command above on the `Exec=` line:

  ```
  Exec=sh -c "wmctrl -x -a Chromium.browser || chromium-browser"
  ```

The first command, before `||`, activates an existing window of Chromium browser. Only if that command fails (`||`, which means "or") the second command is run, i.e., the command needed to run the application. Likely, also the Snap version can be launched with the same command, otherwise you can see in the original `.desktop` file what the correct command line is.

**Remarks**

- You may need to install `wmctrl` first as it is not installed by default. The package bears the same name.
- Snap stores `.desktop` launchers in a specific location, in an "applications" directory under one one of the directories listed in `printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS`. You will easily recognize the path for snaps. Look in the 'applications' directory under that directory to find the `.desktop` file of your Chromium. That is the one you then should copy and edit as indicated above.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it out with my current openbox installation and it worked great. When I'm done with my target user installation, I will of course edit the corresponding `.desktop` file as you wrote.